# Manually set operationId to allow multiple operations with the same verb in Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, asp.net-web-api-routing, swashbuckle

I need to know if it's possible to set up custom operationid, or a naming convention, I mean I know that operation filter can be overwritten the way how operationId is generated

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-swashbuckle-customize/

```
using Swashbuckle.Swagger;
using System.Web.Http.Description;

namespace Something
{
    public class MultipleOperationsWithSameVerbFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(
            Operation operation,
            SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry,
            ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            if (operation.parameters != null)
            {
                operation.operationId += "By";
                foreach (var parm in operation.parameters)
                {
                    operation.operationId += string.Format("{0}",parm.name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in SwaggerConfig.cs

```
 c.OperationFilter<MultipleOperationsWithSameVerbFilter>();
```

Now this is helpful transforming swagger description, check bellow:

[image]

All good, now I endup with another problem, example similar with may cases: on same controller I have two endpoints

- Post: /customer boddy: {email, location....}
- Post: /customer/search boddy: {a filter, whatever}

The example is not quite correct (last post should be a get) but still le assume that webapi cannot be changed (new controller for separation) for this particular case I will try to figure out a way to generate operationId diffrent for each action somehow, but my question is this:

> Is it possible to decorate somehow the controller actions similar with
>   [JsonIgnore] or with [Route("customer/delete")], to be explicit about the **operationId**.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**EDIT** This answer relates to Swashbuckle 5.6 and .NET Framework. Please read [mwilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58567622/502395) for Swashbuckle and .NET Core

You can use the `SwaggerOperationAttribute` provided by Swashbuckle for that.

```
[SwaggerOperation("get")]
public IEnumerable<Contact> Get()
{
    ....
}

[SwaggerOperation("getById")]
public IEnumerable<Contact> Get(string id)
{
    ...
}
```

You can use that attribute to add tags and schemes to your operation as well by the way. Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/Annotations/SwaggerOperationAttribute.cs)

Comment: Shouldn't this be `"Contact_get"` and `"Contact_getById"`?

Comment: For some reason [SwaggerOperation("operationId")] didn't work in our case. Using .Net Core 3.1 and swashbuckle 5.6.0. 
However [HttpGet(Name = "operationId")] works.

Comment: You have to set OperationId property, [SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "MyCustomName")] , NetCore 3.1, swash* 5.2.x

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Visual Studio's Connected Services feature will choke on operation IDs if they contain underscores (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166935/visual-studio-2019-connected-service-reference-openapi-is-generating-duplica)

Comment: Don't forget to add enable Annotations:
`services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>{c.EnableAnnotations();});`

Answer (score 23):

For swashbuckle 5.0, you can use the `Name` attribute. You can set it to any `string` but I'm a fan of using `nameof` like this: `nameof(ActualMethodName)`.

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = nameof(GetProductById))]
public IActionResult GetProductById(int id) // operationId = "GetProductById"'
```

or

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "GetProductById")]
public IActionResult GetProductById(int id) // operationId = "GetProductById"'
```

There are a few other options listed [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#assign-explicit-operationids)

Comment: You can use `[action]` and `[controller]` variables here, too. eg: `[HttpGet(Name = "[controller]_[action]")]` produces `Contact_Get` on the HttpGet method of ContactController.

Comment: see question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63144598/net-core-swashbuckle-set-operationid-automatically-on-all-controller-methods