# Asp.Net core Swashbuckle set operationId

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

How can I set swagger `operationId` attribute in Asp.Net Core 2.1 project? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39435244/1312992) post I should use `SwaggerOperationAttribute` but I cannot find it in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore library. Also there is an `IOperationFilter`

```cs
public interface IOperationFilter
{
    void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context);
}
```

and I can't find any implementations for swagger generation purposes.

Comment: Go directly to the source: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#extend-generator-with-operation-schema--document-filters

Comment: @HelderSepu according to [documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#assign-explicit-operationids) I should specify Name parameter in HttpGet attribute: `[HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "GetById")]`, but it still generates this json: `"operationId": "ApiV1ApplicationsByIdGet"`

Comment: If the documentation says something that is not doing that is potentially a bug, you should report it in the project.

Comment: I think this is a bug, I'm experiencing the same issues after updating to Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 3.0.0.

Comment: Filed: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/921

Comment: Not a bug. I commented on the Github issue: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/921#issuecomment-433293323

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are 2 other options without having to write any extra code or add extra dependency like `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations`

**Option 1**: Convention based - `SwaggerGen` has an option to set `CustomOperationIds`. So you can simply set it to use `ControllerName_HttpMethod` like this:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.CustomOperationIds(e => $"{e.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["controller"]}_{e.HttpMethod}");
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Test API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

This will add operationIds to all your methods, following `ControllerName_HttpMethod` convention.

**Option 2**: ActionFilter/Attribute based - you can configure each Action method (as you'd do with `SwaggerOperation` action filter by simple adding a `Name` property to your HTTP verb action filter like this:

```cs
[HttpPost(Name="Post_Person")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
public async Task<ActionResult<Response>> PostAsync([FromBody]Request request)
{
    Response result = await _context.PostAsync(request);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

This works exactly like `[SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "Post_Person")]` but without the need of `EnableAnnotations`

Comment: Is there a way to have `Swashbuckle` infer the `Name` based on the method name? In the example above, have it infer the name `PostAsync`?

Comment: @phoenix A late answer. Simply change to `ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"]` would work. I've added another answer below too.

Answer (score 9):

Adding a `Name` parameter to `[HttpGet]`/`[HttpPost]` fails with an exception in the most recent version, but putting a `Name` parameter on the `Route` attribute seems to work:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Get all devices
/// </summary>
[Route("devices", Name = "GetAllDevices")]
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[Produces(typeof(Device[]))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllDevices() { ...}
```

Comment: I concur! Many thanks. The exception I get is that standard routing is not allowed with ApiExplorer or something like that.
I think this is the 'correct', currently.

Answer (score 7):

You can also generate the operation id based on the action name which is the method name, I found this handy when generating the API client.

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.CustomOperationIds(e => $"{e.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"]}");
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Test API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can enable annotation on swagger with the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations NuGet package. (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations)

Once annotations have been enabled, you can enrich the generated Operation metadata by decorating actions with a SwaggerOperationAttribute.

```cs
[HttpPost]

[SwaggerOperation(
    Summary = "Creates a new product",
    Description = "Requires admin privileges",
    OperationId = "CreateProduct",
    Tags = new[] { "Purchase", "Products" }
)]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody]Product product)
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I came to this solution:

```cs
public class SwaggerOperationNameFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        operation.OperationId = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .Union(context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
            .OfType<SwaggerOperationAttribute>()
            .Select(a => a.OperationId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class SwaggerOperationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SwaggerOperationAttribute(string operationId)
    {
        OperationId = operationId;
    }

    public string OperationId { get; }
}

// Startup.cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...
    c.OperationFilter<SwaggerOperationNameFilter>();
};

[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
[SwaggerOperation("GetById")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

But it still seems to me that I've reinvented the wheel.

Comment: `public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id)` Something like that did not work, Yes looks like you are reinventing  the wheel

Answer (score 3):

Its pretty simple

Add `EnableAnnotations` in ConfigureService Method

```
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "Project HTTP API",
                    Version = "v1",
                    Description = "...."
                });
                options.EnableAnnotations();
            });
```

And use in controllers

```
[SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "GET_API")]
```

You can see in this in Swagger Json as

```
get": {
        "tags": [
          "API"
        ],
        "summary": "....",
        "operationId": "GET_API"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line -
swagger.CustomOperationIds(e => $"{e.RelativePath}");
in services.AddSwaggerGen function call