# AspNetCore Custom/Explicit Swagger OperationId

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am creating restful APIs using aspnet core 2.2. I have a standard setup where each model has it's own controller with a `GET` and a `POST` actions. I am using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` NUGET package and using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle) article from Microsoft docs.

Now, when I look at the generated swagger file, it has multiple GET and POST operationIds. How can I configure custom operationIds without using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations`?

Here's what my Action methods look like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
public async Task<ActionResult<Response>> PostAsync([FromBody]Request request)
{
    Response result = await _context.PostAsync(request);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

I have multiple controllers, they're all following the same pattern.

My Startup class looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    });

    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    });

    ...
}
```

I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52262826/asp-net-core-swashbuckle-set-operationid?rq=1) solution, but don't want to go that route.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After spending couple of hours trying to find the best solution, I found 2 approaches:

**Option 1**: Convention based - `SwaggerGen` has an option to set `CustomOperationIds`. So you can simply set it to use `ControllerName_HttpMethod` like this:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.CustomOperationIds(e => $"{e.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["controller"]}_{e.HttpMethod}");
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "ID&V API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

This will add operationIds to all your methods, following `ControllerName_HttpMethod` convention.

**Option 2**: ActionFilter/Attribute based - you can configure each Action method (as you'd do with `SwaggerOperation` action filter by simple adding a `Name` property to your HTTP verb action filter like this:

```
[HttpPost(Name="Post_Person")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
public async Task<ActionResult<Response>> PostAsync([FromBody]Request request)
{
    Response result = await _context.PostAsync(request);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

This works exactly like `[SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "Post_Person")]` but without the need of `EnableAnnotations`

`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#assign-explicit-operationids)