# Net Core: Swashbuckle Set operationId Automatically on to Controller Action Method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

We are trying to override Swashbuckle/Swagger IO CodeGen naming conventions, when its creating Angular API Service Proxies, for existing 500+ controllers and the corresponding methods.

Currently linking Net Core 3 APIs with Angular Typescript.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58567622/13889515

The following answer works:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = nameof(GetProductById))]
public IActionResult GetProductById(int id) // operationId = "GetProductById"'

[HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "GetProductById")]
public IActionResult GetProductById(int id) // operationId = "GetProductById"'
```

Is there a way to loop through all controllers and methods in startup? Name should equal name of Action Method within Controller.

This maybe possible solution, However, I need the action value.

```
return services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.CustomOperationIds(e => $"{e.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["controller"]}_{e.HttpMethod}");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54294810/13889515

Comment: I think if you wanted to live on the risky side, you could technically do a giant search/replace with `Name = "[controller]_[action]"` That would assume the `[Http(...)]` attribute was already present

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize this piece of code:

```
return services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.CustomOperationIds(e => $"{e.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"]}");
```