# Modify Web API action name generated by Swagger

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have a Web API project which is integrated with [Swagger](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle). I am using a low code platform IDE [OutSystems](https://www.outsystems.com/) to consume the REST API.

Outsystems IDE takes following URL to generate REST methods:

http://10.0.0.11/PortalService/swagger/docs/v1

I have the following action method in my web API project:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/LoanApplications")]
public IHttpActionResult AllLoanApplicationsByUser(string userID, [FromUri]List<string> lstInstitutionId)
```

For this method Swagger is generating following method name:

```
Dashboard_AllLoanApplicationsByUser
```

How to configure Swagger to generate method name similar to the action name from code?

Note: Dashboard is the name of the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39435244/1169180).

This is what I was looking for:

```
[SwaggerOperation("MethodName")]
```